# Confused if google rejected my update or not

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

I recently uploaded a new apk which google rejected due to permission problems.

Today I uploaded a new apk, which I hope fixed the problems.

However, I am confused if its been rejected again or not.

On the main page I see like this:

[image]

Which shows last update with todays date and says rejected.

But then when I go into the dashboard, I see:

[image]

which seems to indicate that they are processing the update. Also, it got rejected very quickly, which makes me think that they still are updating it.

Can anyone clarify this for me. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is misleading, but the app is in review. The new google play console is a bit clearer. Obviously the main page shows you that the old update was rejected, but when you go into the dashboard it shows you that it is processing update. Bottom line, be patient the app is in review.